# Does the T CreateObject<T> in Entity Framework also track changes after creating the proxy?

Tags: entity-framework-4

I thought that calling ObjectContext.CreateObject() created a proxy wrapper for T and then started tracking changes using the change notification supported by the proxy wrapper.  If so, then why can't I detach it from the context?

Here is my problem:

```
public void FailedTest() {
    POCOtype fail = context.CreateObject<POCOtype>();

    context.Detach(fail);  // Throws InvalidOperationException 
    //  "The object cannot be detached because it is not attached to the ObjectStateManager."
}

public void WorkingTest() {
    POCOtype happy = context.CreateObject<POCOtype>();
    context.AttachTo("POCOtypes", happy);
    context.Detach(happy);

    // Everything is good.
}

public void VeryOdd_WorkingTest() {
    POCOtype odd = context.CreateObject<POCOtype>();

    try {
        context.Detach(odd);  // Throws InvalidOperationException 
    //  "The object cannot be detached because it is not attached to the ObjectStateManager."
    } catch(Exception e) { }

    context.SaveChanges(); // The object is inserted into the DB.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateObject` doesn't create attached entity. You must manually attach or add entity to the context yourselves. You can even attach it to other context instance. Your last test should not insert the entity. I just test it myself and it didn't insert anything. Use new instance of the context for the test or check that `context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)` returns no entries before you call `CreateObject`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  My bad... it was being tied via an association with an attached entity, so it was getting attached--just not until later in the code.